# JavaFX how to get menubar on the bottom

Tags: layout, javafx, menubar

I'm trying to put the menu bar on the bottom of a windows, here are a example made in paint

but I don't have enough reputation so isn't like this

```
________________________________________
|                                   _ x| 
|                                      |
|                                      |
|                                      |
|                                      |
|                                      |
|                                      |
|file | Edit | view|                   |                                        
|______________________________________|
```

Answer (score 2):

To create menu you should use `MenuBar` component, which you can add using any layout.

For your use case you can **use `BorderPane` and set `MenuBar` to the bottom**

Example code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

            Menu menu1 = new Menu("File");
            Menu menu2 = new Menu("Edit");
            Menu menu3 = new Menu("View");

            MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
            menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menu1, menu2, menu3);

            root.setBottom(menuBar);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eugener: since I had it already, I added the example code. Hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: Of course I don't - thanks! But, in general, I prefer not to do it for that kind of questions. Just the idea is enough - we don't want to promote laziness here :)